# yocto build error, cmake-native_3.16.5.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

Tags: yocto, qemu, openembedded

Error screenshot

[image: 1]

I'm facing that problem since a while
I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

here is the error message, also shown in attatched picture

```
ERROR: Task (/home/ahmedshindy/yocto-labs/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake/cmake-native_3.16.5.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

tutorial I'm following:
[Getting started with Embedded Linux and Yocto project - building for vexpress-a9 target complete with u-boot bootloader and sdcard emulation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/getting-started-embedded-linux-yocto-project-building-ahmed-kassem/)

I'm expecting to build successfully

Comment: I don't know after which step you're getting this error but try to clean everything with bitbake -c cleanall <recipe-name>. After that try to do clean build.

Comment: I'm getting another one, maybe it is the problem

ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/ahmedshindy/yocto42/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/swig/swig_4.1.1.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
Waiting for 2 running tasks to finish: